# Failed to compile create-react-app.Cannot find module "ReactPropTypesSecret"

Tags: create-react-app

Every time i try to 'npm start' my create-react-app project ,it throws this error saying

> ./src/index.js
>
> Error: Cannot find module './lib/ReactPropTypesSecret'
>
> Referenced from:

And I couldn't really find out what's causing this error.

Comment: What version of `npm` do you have installed?

Comment: @JanezKuhar version 6.5.0

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Try re-installing `Node` and create your app from scratch as suggested here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#quick-overview